Understanding $\mathcal G$ in $\Bbb C$.
Construction:
Define $\mathcal F$ by the union of leaves:
$$\mathcal F:=\bigg \lbrace \mathcal M[\chi_t(x)]\cup \mathcal M\bigg[\frac{1}{1-\chi_r(x)}\bigg] \bigg \rbrace$$
where $\mathcal M$ denotes the Mellin transform for real parameters $t\ge 0$ and $r>0$ indexing the leaves.
In particular we have that:
$$\mathcal M[\chi_t(x)]:=\int_{(0,1)} \chi_t(x)x^{s-1}~dx=  2\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{ts})=\Phi_t(s) $$
for Bessel function $K_1$
and
$$  \mathcal M\bigg[\frac{1}{1-\chi_r(x)}\bigg] :=\int_{(0,1)} \frac{1}{1-\chi_r(x)}x^{s-1}~dx= \Psi_r(s)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Phi_{rn}(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\sqrt{\frac{rn}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{rs})$$
$\mathcal F$ therefore defines a collection of functions $\Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ by definition of the Mellin transform. Now, take the collection:
$$\mathcal G=\bigg\lbrace \Psi_r(s) \cup \Psi_r(-s) \cup -\Psi_r(s) \cup -\Psi_r(-s) \cup \Phi_t(s) \cup \Phi_t(-s) \cup -\Phi_t(s) \cup -\Phi_t(-s) \bigg\rbrace $$
If we restrict our Mellin transforms to $(0,1)\to \Bbb R$ then this indeed gives a foliation of $\Bbb R^2 - \lbrace \mathrm{x~axis} \cup \mathrm{y~axis} \rbrace$. I'm wondering what happens when one takes the natural codomain i.e. $\Bbb C$, of the Mellin transform, and applies the same construction.
Question:

Does $\mathcal G$ form a foliation of $\Bbb C - \lbrace \mathrm{im.~axis \cup re. axis}  \rbrace$? I'm struggling to understand what changes when the codomain of the Mellin transform changes from the restricted $\Bbb R$ to the natural $\Bbb C.$

Attempt:
I calculated the fundamental strip for $\Phi_1(s)$ to be $\Re(s)>0 \cup \Im(s)>0$. I am having problems how to proceed in calculating the fundamental strips for $\Psi_r(s)$ due to the infinite sum. But if this could be done then I could answer this question.
Easier question:

What are the fundamental strips for $\Psi_r(s)$?

Edit:
It is probably helpful to include that user @CalebBriggs calculated the analytic continuation of a related function:
$$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\sqrt{ns}K_1(2\sqrt{ns})$$
$$=\frac{1}{s} + -\frac{1}{2} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{s^{n}}{n!^{2}}\left(\zeta(-n)\left(1+n\ln(s)-2n\psi(1+n)\right)-n\zeta'(-n)\right)$$
which is an analytic function on the Riemann surface associated with the logarithm.
